# BlackBerry 5.0 check directory content

Tags: blackberry

my doubt is as simple as title.

I have an X directory where im going to have some images, and i need to send each image of the directory in a mail.

No idea how to check the contest of the directory, and list each file of it so i can send it in a mail.

is it possible?

THX in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
try {
     FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/X");
     // If no exception is thrown, then the URI is valid, but the file may or may not exist.
     if (fconn.exists() && fconn.isDirectory())
         Enumeration list = fconn.list();
         while (list.hasMoreElements()) {
              String fname = (String)list.nextElement();
              //fname could be a file or a sub-directory ...
         }
         fconn.close();
 }
     catch (IOException ioe) {
 }
```